# Twitter like photos and videos layout css and or javascript

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, layout, twitter

I would like to know how twitter lays its "photos and videos" images out so I can apply it to the images I am posting on my wordpress. I'm hoping there is some form of jquery library that this can be done with.

Here's a link to an image of what I'm talking about

http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t569/Corbin1988/twitteralbum_zps420f1f1c.jpg?t=1392754972

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help I might receive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit more straight forward, but jquery.gpop. check out the "flexible grid" at the bottom.

http://vanamco.com/jquery.gpop/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

A jquery library that can also accomplish the look I was originally going for is [Justified Image Grid](http://justifiedgrid.com/).